# C++ Beginner - While loop repeating first iteration

Tags: c++

All,

So I've been really racking my brain about this one. I have a section of my program that needs to count spaces/vowels/characters in a user-specified string. This is one of those "teach you the way no one would do it because you can only used what we've covered in class already" kinds of assignments. So I have the user input a text, ending with a sentinel char, which in this case is '#'. The loop works wonderfully in regards to exiting when the sentinel is encountered, but it keeps iterating twice over string[0]. Here's the code:

```
i = 0;
characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i);

while (characterToBeProcessed != LOOP_SENTINEL)
{
    fout << characterToBeProcessed;

    // Convert to lowercase
    characterToBeProcessed = 
        static_cast<char> (tolower(characterToBeProcessed)); 

    // Increment character counters
    switch (characterToBeProcessed)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            totalVowelCount++;
            totalCharacterCount++;
            break;
        case ' ':
            totalSpaceCount++;
            totalCharacterCount++;
            break;
        default:
            totalCharacterCount++;
            break;
    }
    characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i++);
}
```

So when I input at the prompt:

```
"Please input a text to be analyzed, ending with the # character: "

 Hi there, my friend!#
```

The output is:

```
Below is the text entered by the user: 

HHi there, my friend!

Total characters: 21
Total vowels: 5
Total blank spaces: 3
```

I've had the program output the chars for .at(0) and .at(1), and those give me the correct characters, I just can't figure out why the loop iterates twice for the first char and then works fine after that second time through. The counts/output are otherwise correct except for the first char being duplicated. Any appreciation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Consider the difference between i++ and ++i.

Comment: So DEEPLY sorry that I didn't read all the side documentation or teach myself how to use VS debugger first. My SINCEREST apologies for commit such a serious crime.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the right way to solve problems of this kind is to use a debugger.  It would save you lots and lots of time.

But in any case, your error is that at the end of your `while` loop, you do this:

```
characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i++);
```

But before your `while` loop, you do this:

```
characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i);
```

Your problem is that you are not incrementing `i` each time you use it, which naturally results in the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A character at the first position is read twice

```
i = 0;
characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i);
                                      ^^^^^^

while (characterToBeProcessed != LOOP_SENTINEL)
{
    //...
    characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i++);
                                          ^^^^^^^^  
}
```

If you need to use the while loop then it can look like

```
i = 0;

while ( ( characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at( i++) ) != LOOP_SENTINEL )
{
    //...
    // remove the next statement
    // characterToBeProcessed = userInputText.at(i++);
}
```

Also this statement

```
totalCharacterCount++;
```

is used under each label. It is better to place it outside the switch statement either before it or after it. For example

```
totalCharacterCount++;

switch (characterToBeProcessed)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        totalVowelCount++;
        break;
    case ' ':
        totalSpaceCount++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, got it working. I appreciate your time.